# Simplest IDE and DB to use to create a simple login page in Ubuntu? (Language agnostic)

Tags: c#, linux, database, ubuntu, desktop-application

I need to make a simple desktop app that can at least receive User ID and PW, store in a database file like MS Access, and retrieve again from the DB. I was using Windows Forms in MSVS2010 and MS Access before I had to switch to Ubuntu. Any alternatives?

This is for an assignment so the simpler the better. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to search anything? Try read about PostgreSQL\MySQL and Net.Core

Comment: [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html) is probably what you are looking for in a database solution, but .Net on Linux is mainly geared toward server software - console apps and Asp.Net websites. I don't think there is support for Forms, though you may find an open source project for creating user interfaces.